# How to make border follow the cursor in the top navigation bar on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, swipe

I have a question. I am making a webpage and I got an idea that the top navigation bar would follow my cursor. Basically, I would like that the border around each link in the top bar would follow where I move my mouse cursor. I got this idea from iOS (specifically from photos) that has a lot of these cool features. Any idea how to accomplish this?

I am also providing you with a link to google drive where I posted the video because as I know you currently can't upload the video directly here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17nqIWUtp0Smr4I8RzWJDahjYioLxtwdQ/view?usp=sharing

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please share any code you have tried already. People are very willing to help but SO isn't an ab initio code-writing service. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, not very adaptative. Can't think about something better right now :

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  background : #000;
  padding:20px;
  margin:0;
}
div {
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0 5px;
  position: relative;
  font-size:0;
  display:inline-block
}
.highlight {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  top: calc(50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: -100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: left .2s ease, width .2s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: 6px;
  width:0;
  opacity: 0;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  z-index: 999;
  position:relative;
  transition: color 0 .2s;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000
}
a:hover ~ .highlight {
  opacity: 1;
}
a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .highlight {
  left: 0px;
  width: 39px;
}
a:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .highlight {
  width: 42px;
  left: 50px;
}
a:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .highlight {
  left: 104px;
  width: 35px;
}
a:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .highlight {
  left: 152px;
  width: 59px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Years</a>
  <a href="#">Month</a>
  <a href="#">Days</a>
  <a href="#">All photos</a>
  <div class="highlight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want to have. I should have shared my code for better understanding so here it is. I would just like to have the inner border you made to follow the cursor and the outer one to not exist. Here is the link to the code on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Y3Y3OkNdAxJGoaH_5oxwVahJyYnj1Oax?usp=sharing

Comment: They are not borders but backgrounds. Check my code and you'll be able to understand what I did. Just remove `background: #333` from the div styling and you'll be okay